# react fire multiple function in an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
fireOne(){

}

render(){
   return(
     <p onClick={this.fireOne.bind(this)}></p>
   )
}
```

Can I bind one event with 2 function? one function is for current component, I want to pass something down to the children component as well.

Comment: if you wanna pass something down to children, then you can set state of parent component on click and then pass it as a prop to children.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to acomplish, but I'm not completely sure:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  foo1 = () => { console.log('ahh');}
  
  foo2 = () => { console.log('beh');}
  
  render() {
    return(<div onClick={() => {
      this.foo1();
      this.foo2();
    }}>AHH </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: why use arrow function? why can't it be `foo1(){...}`?

Comment: Right you can use it without an arrow function especially if you are not referencing `this` in there. However, using arrow function works as well if you don't like to see the word `function` at all, it just depends on you just make sure you know when to use it or not.

Comment: @giala On your question you have: this.fireOne.bind(this), so I assumed you want to keep the context, this is a nicer way to do it, performance wise.